# Facebook C# SDK using multiple id´s in a single request (call) to FB Graph Api

Tags: c#, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I would like to request the images fields from multiple target id´s (included in feed attachments).

For example the single request would be like `id?fields=images`, but I would like to request for multiple id´s. Is there a way to do so? If yes, what is the correct syntax? I've tried `id,id?fields=images`, but that did not work.

I am using Graph api V2.4 with a GET command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for doing so is:

?ids=album_object_one_id,album_object_two_id&fields=images